# Argument 2 passed to Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::download() must be of the type string, object given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, maatwebsite-excel

> Argument 2 passed to Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::download() must be of
>   the type string, object given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\student_route\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php
>   on line 237

```
public function excel_report()
    {
     $student_data = DB::table('student_details')->get()->toArray();
     $student_array[] = array('Name', 'Address', 'Roll No', 'Class');
     foreach($student_data as $student)
     {
      $student_array[] = array(
       'Student Name'  => $student->st_name,
       'Address'   => $student->address,
       'Roll No'   => $student->roll_no,
       'Class'    => $student->st_class
      );
     }
     Excel::download('Student_Data', function($excel) use ($student_array){
      $excel->setTitle('Student Datas');
      $excel->sheet('Student_Datass', function($sheet) use ($student_array){
       $sheet->fromArray($student_array, null, 'A1', false, false);
      });
     })->download('xlsx');
    }
```

> I got error Argument 2 passed to Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::download()
>   must be of the type string, object given.don't know where is issue.
>   anyone check please. i am using laravel 5.8

Comment: Looks like the second parameter is the filename https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/architecture/#download-the-file

Comment: Why do you expect that code to do what you want?

Comment: @NicoHaase i want to download array in excel.

Comment: And why do you use invalid code for that? There should not be a closure given as the second argument, as the error message clearly states

Comment: @NicoHaase if you know please write correct code.

Answer (score 2):

As of  `maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel 3.1`

Excel::download method's signature is changed
to

`public function download($export, string $fileName, string $writerType = null, array $headers = [])`

download expects 2nd argument as string, callback is no longer there.
see this upgrade [guide](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/upgrade.html) here

If you want to keep using sane behavior of v2.1. you can use this package [convenia/excel](https://packagist.org/packages/convenia/excel)

as an alternative.

This helps when you want to keep up to date with latest laravel versions without making changes to your import/ export code.

If you have less import / export functionalities then I would recommend to change it according to `maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel 3.1`

Comment: Thank you for convenia/excel package! I never know it exist

Answer (score 1):

I haven't use that package, but you can see from the [method signature](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/blob/3.1/src/Excel.php#L81) that the second argument expects a `string` that will be the name of the file to download:

```
public function download($export, string $fileName, string $writerType = null, array $headers = [])
```

In your case, you are returning a `callback`.

---

## Update 1

<s>Seeing the docs, I think that you what you are trying to use the static `create` method of the `Excel` class, but instead you are using (incorrectly) the download one. From the</s> [docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/array.html):

> ## Creating a sheet from an array
>
> ### Array
>
> To create a new file from an array use `->fromArray($source,
>   $nullValue, $startCell, $strictNullComparison, $headingGeneration)`
>   inside the sheet `closure`.
>
> ```
> Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) {
>
>     $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) {
>
>         $sheet->fromArray(array(
>             array('data1', 'data2'),
>             array('data3', 'data4')
>         ));
>
>     });
>
> })->export('xls');
> ```

<s>So, in your case, replace the first `download](...)` with `create(...)`:</s>

```
public function excel_report()
{
    $student_data = DB::table('student_details')->get()->toArray();
    $student_array[] = array('Name', 'Address', 'Roll No', 'Class');

    foreach ($student_data as $student)
    {
        $student_array[] = array(
            'Student Name' => $student->st_name,
            'Address'      => $student->address,
            'Roll No'      => $student->roll_no,
            'Class'        => $student->st_class
        );
    }

    Excel::create('Student_Data', function ($excel) use ($student_array) {
//        ^^^^^^^
        $excel->setTitle('Student Datas');
        $excel->sheet('Student_Datass', function ($sheet) use ($student_array) {
            $sheet->fromArray($student_array, null, 'A1', false, false);
        });
    })->export('xls');
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

---

## Update 2

The above code works for `v2`, but given that you are using the `v3` this can't help you. In the current version, you can format your output file with a combination of `Export`s and `Sheet` classes. Actually, this is more modular approach to decouple and improve your code. Check [this section](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/multiple-sheets.html) of the docs.

Comment: how??"""""""""""

Comment: @zeeshan I'll improve my answer.

Comment: Excel::create() is removed and replaced by Excel::download/Excel::store($yourExport)
3.0 provides no convenience methods for styling, you are encouraged to use PhpSpreadsheets native methods.

Comment: i am using this version https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.0/getting-started/installation.html

Comment: Yes I've just read that. But what is the problem? you can create several Export classes, this will format the output as good as you want. You can handle [arrays](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/collection.html) also so you can custom the file like you want.