# Laravel Excel Export - Type error: Argument 2 passed to Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::download() must be of the type string

Tags: php, excel, laravel

On my **StudentController**:

```
//data collection
$all_students= Student::with('Customer')->where('std', $name)->get();

//create a new array
$student_array[] = array();

//loop and set array indexes
foreach ($all_studentsas $student)
        {
            $student_array[] = array(
                'description' => $student['description'],
                'cost'       => $student['cost']
            );
        }

return Excel::download('Student_Data', function ($excel) {

                    $excel->setTitle('Student Data');
                    $excel->sheet('Student_Data', function ($sheet) {
                        $sheet->fromArray($student_array);
                    });
                })->download('xls');
```

I tried so many [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56202056/argument-2-passed-to-maatwebsite-excel-exceldownload-must-be-of-the-type-str) given but couldn't fix this **issue**.

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::download()
>   must be of the type string, object given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php
>   on line 221

Can anyone point me where I did wrong here and what should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: This is a typo. You're calling `Excel::download(...)->download()`, but that should be `Excel::create(...)->download()`

Comment: `create()` doesn't support brother. that's why I used `download()`. Also I can use `store()`. But the same error appears

Comment: when I use it `Call to undefined method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::create()` error appears

Comment: What version of this are you on? 3.1?

Comment: `"maatwebsite/excel": "^3.0",`

Comment: Ah, that's the issue. The `Excel::create()->download()` approach is for version 2.1. Hmm... You'll have to review https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/ on how to achieve this in the newer version.

Comment: I'll try it, brother. Thanks a lot